# Generic method with multiple constraints

Tags: c#, generics, .net-3.5

I have a generic method which has two generic parameters. I tried to compile the code below but it doesn't work. Is it a .NET limitation? Is it possible to have multiple constraints for different parameter?

```
public TResponse Call<TResponse, TRequest>(TRequest request)
  where TRequest : MyClass, TResponse : MyOtherClass
```

Answer (score 525, accepted):

It is possible to do this, you've just got the syntax slightly wrong. You need a [`where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) for each constraint rather than separating them with a comma:

```
public TResponse Call<TResponse, TRequest>(TRequest request)
    where TRequest : MyClass
    where TResponse : MyOtherClass
```

Comment: Can you have multiple restraints on the same generic like `where T : MyClass where T : MyOtherClass` ?

Comment: @WDUK Sort of. C# does not allow multiple inheritance. However, you can specify some interfaces and other special conditions, as well as the single class. Each requirement is separated by a comma (partially why Martin's attempt was not valid C#: commas in that context already meant something else). So, `where T : MyClass, IMyInterface` is valid, but `where T : MyClass, MyOtherClass` is not.

Answer (score 25):

In addition to the main answer by @LukeH with another usage, we can use multiple interfaces instead of class. (One class and n count interfaces) like this

```
public TResponse Call<TResponse, TRequest>(TRequest request)
  where TRequest : MyClass, IMyOtherClass, IMyAnotherClass
```

or

```
public TResponse Call<TResponse, TRequest>(TRequest request)
  where TRequest : IMyClass,IMyOtherClass
```

Answer (score 12):

In addition to the main answer by @LukeH, I have issue with dependency injection, and it took me some time to fix this. It is worth to share, for those who face the same issue:

```
public interface IBaseSupervisor<TEntity, TViewModel> 
    where TEntity : class
    where TViewModel : class
```

It is solved this way. in containers/services the key is typeof and the comma (,)

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IBaseSupervisor<,>), typeof(BaseSupervisor<,>));
```

This was mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43087821/how-to-add-a-generic-dependency-injection/43094684#43094684).

Comment: This answer is not related to type constraints at all. It is about unbound generic types and how to spell them out in C#. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2173115/2157640 https://stackoverflow.com/a/6607299/2157640

Answer (score 6):

Each constraint need to be on own line and if there are more of them for single generic parameter then they need to separated by comma.

```
public TResponse Call<TResponse, TRequest>(TRequest request)
    where TRequest : MyClass 
    where TResponse : MyOtherClass, IOtherClass
```

Edited as per comment

Comment: This answer is incorrect, both in the comma following MyClass (see most upvoted answer) and the claim constraints need to be on separate lines. I'd fix it, but the edit queue is full.

Comment: Thanks @ToddWest. I have removed the additional comma after `MyClass`