# C# generics syntax for multiple type parameter constraints

Tags: c#, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generic methods and multiple constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588643/generic-methods-and-multiple-constraints)

I need a generic function that has two type constraints, each inheriting from a different base class. I know how to do this with one type:

```
void foo<T>() where T : BaseClass
```

However, I don't know how to do this with two types:

```
void foo<TOne, TTwo>() where TOne : BaseOne // and TTwo : BaseTwo ???
```

How do you do this? (using .NET 2)

Answer (score 874, accepted):

```
void foo<TOne, TTwo>() 
   where TOne : BaseOne
   where TTwo : BaseTwo
```

More info here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#constraining-multiple-parameters

Comment: Search for "Constraining Multiple Parameters" if you don't want to read it all.

Comment: Is it possible to have a constrain that would do this:  `void foo<TOne, TTwo>() 
   where TOne : Class
   where TTwo : Class where TOne != TTwo` so basically we don't know what TOne and TTwo are except that they are reference types but cannot be the same

Comment: @IronHide: I'd love to be proven wrong here ... but I'm 99% sure this isn't possible :)

Comment: And how to use ExtensionMethod with multiple generics