# How do I implement ISerializable on a class with [Serializable] when I want to do exactly what it would do if I hadn't added ISerializable?

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, reflection

I have a class with some data I'm serializing:

```
[Serializable]
public class SomeData {
    public int NumericField;
    public string StringField;
}
```

I have a nice convenient extension method:

```
public static string ToJson<T> (this T value) {
    // yay no compile-time checks for [Serializable]?
    if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
        throw new SerializationException("Object lacks [Serializable] attribute");

    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
        using (var writer = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8)) {
            serializer.WriteObject(writer, value);
        }

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

I'd really rather my class `SomeData` implemented `ISerializable`, but when I add it, I'm told I need to add a method:

```
error CS0535: 'SomeData' does not implement interface member
System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable.GetObjectData(
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, 
System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'
```

The problem is just that I want it to do **exactly** what it currently does, but also restrict `ToJson<T>` to `ISerializable` classes so no one will ever accidentally pass it something that would throw an avoidable exception.  Like this:

```
public static string ToJson<T> (this T value) where T : ISerializable
```

Is there a concise implementation of `GetObjectData` or some other trick that will just replicate the exact behavior I would get if I don't add the `ISerializable` interface?  I want something I can just include in a class I inherit, or something concise (and always exactly the same) I can just paste into all the classes where I just want exactly what `[Serializable]` does to happen.  Something generic.  Performance is not a huge concern, but I can only use .Net Framework 3.5.

UPDATE:

I'm perfectly willing to use `[DataContract]` in the place of `[Serializable]`, but if I did that, is there a generic way I could implement `ISerializable` so it just does exactly what `[DataContract]` would do if I hadn't implemented `ISerializable`? (same qn as above with `DataContract` everywhere you see `Serializable`)

Comment: I did think of one solution that gets me partway - I could just add an empty interface to all my `[Serializable]` classes and just restrict on that, even if it's empty.  I guess that won't expose my extension method to any ISerializable classes that happen to be about, though, which would be nice...

Comment: @caesay this does not work - this syntax applies both constraints, not one OR the other.  This can kinda work if you make two extension methods with different names, one constrained on `ISerializable` and the other on `CustomInterface`, but again it's not really what I want.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need `ISerializable` at all, nor do you need to throw the `SerializationException` yourself. `DataContractJsonSerializer` would throw an exception if the type is not serializable.
There are actually several options for a type to be serializable using this serializer:

- Serializable attribute
- DataContract attribute
- ISerializable interface
- Nothing (would work for public types and serialize all public fields and properties)

Letting the serializer perform the check would support all of them.

There could not be a compile-time check for serializability (without investing in a Roslyn analyzer that provides some supports for this). Marking an object as `Serializable` or even implementing the `ISerializable` interface does not guarantee that the serializer wouldn't encounter an non-serializable type in the object graph and throw an exception at runtime.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer my question, but I may remove `[Serializable]` until I have a solution (didn't realize I could omit it).  The point is to enforce an appropriate compile time check, and also not have auto-complete suggest my extension method for everything all the time.

Comment: also, why would the `DataContractJsonSerializer` ever throw an exception?

Comment: So because the compile-time check won't prevent all possible exceptions, I should get rid of it even if it catches the errors I want to detect?

I understand that `DataContract` and `DataMember` are alternatives to `Serializable`, but they'd leave me with the exact same question, substituting `DataContract` in the place of `Serializable`.  (I'd be happy with that answer, too, incidentally)

Comment: How could I do that, Eli? isn't `[Serializable]` the marker interface, and can't be checked at compile time?

Answer (score 0):

1. As you yourself commented, add a blank interface and put it as a constraint in your extension method. You can also add ISerializable as a constraint [C# generics syntax for multiple type parameter constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965580/c-sharp-generics-syntax-for-multiple-type-parameter-contraints)
2. Another option is to inherit a base class that implements ISerializable and the required methods

Comment: Also, the question you linked to isn't about adding multiple constraints on a single type, but rather how to add constraints when you have multiple type parameters...

Answer (score 0):

To work around this behavior, implement the ISerializable.GetObjectData method in the converted Visual C# .NET class. To do this, add the following code in the converted Visual C# .NET class:

```
void System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable.GetObjectData(
    System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
    System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
{
    // Code as required
}
```