# How do i define a function with multiple type in one input parameter?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to implement a Google Mobile Ads in unity, and I see [RegisterEventHandlers](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/rewarded#listen_to_rewarded_ad_events) to handle some event for `RewardedAd` and `InterstitialAd`. I've seen their [example](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/tree/main/samples/HelloWorld) but they defined the `RegisterEventHandlers` one by one even though the event name is same, and I intend to create one `RegisterEventHandlers` to handle both `RewardedAd` and `InterstitialAd` event.

> Please forgive me if it’s a basic question, I’ve only been learning Unity and c# for less than 3 weeks.

I've tried to defined a `RegisterEventHandlers` but I'm stuck about how do I defined an input parameter that accept `RewardedAd` and `InterstitialAd` type like this

```cs
private static RewardedAd _rewardBaseVideo;
private static InterstitialAd _interstitialAd;

private void RequestAdmobRewardVideo()
{
  //another code
  _rewardBaseVideo = ad;
  RegisterEventHandlers(ad);
}

private void RequestAdmobInterstitial()
{
  //another code
  _interstitialAd = ad;
  // Error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'GoogleMobileAds.Api.InterstitialAd' to 'GoogleMobileAds.Api.RewardedAd'
  RegisterEventHandlers(ad);
}

// how do I dynamically declaring `RewardedAd` and `InterstitialAd` input type
private void RegisterEventHandlers(RewardedAd ad)
{
}
```

I've also tried to defined RegisterEventHandlers like this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/965593/8943429):

```
private void RegisterEventHandlers<T>(T ad) where T: RewardedAd, InterstitialAd
{
}
```

but I got an error `The class type constraint 'InterstitialAd' must come before any other constraints`.

so how do i defined RegisterEventHandlers gracefully accept both `RewardedAd` and `InterstitialAd`?

Comment: Read the last comment under this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/588681/920069

Comment: @RetiredNinja I'm missed to read the comment, but i don't get it about _if you have common code then have each call that third function_, could you elaborate it?

Comment: I don't see clear reason to break the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) of the SOLID Principles of Object Oriented Programming, in this case.