# What exactly is an "open generic type" in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, open-generics

I was going through [Asp.Net MVC lesson](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-34-cs.aspx) and learned that, for a method to qualify as an action for a controller,

- It must not have an **"open generic type"**

I understand generics somewhat and use them to some extent, but:

- What is an **open generic type** in .Net.
- Is there such a thing as a **closed generic type**?
- **Open generic type** is a term not used very often. What is used / confused with it ?

Answer (score 241, accepted):

The C# language defines an open type to be a type that's either a type argument or a generic type defined with unknown type arguments:

> All types can be classified as either open types or closed types. An *open type* is a type that involves type parameters. More specifically:
>
> - A type parameter defines an open type.
> - An array type is an open type if and only if its element type is an open type.
> - A *constructed type* is an open type if and only if one or more of its type arguments is an *open type*. A *constructed nested type* is an open type if and only if one or more of its type arguments or the type arguments of its containing type(s) is an open type.
>
> A *closed type* is a type that is not an open type.

Therefore `T`, `List<T>`, and `Dictionary<string,T>`, and `Dictionary<T,U>` are all open types (`T` and `U` are type arguments) whereas `List<int>` and `Dictionary<string,int>` are closed types.

There's a related concept: An *unbound generic type* is a generic type with unspecified type arguments. An unbound type can't be used in expressions other than `typeof()` and you can't instantiate it or call its methods. For instance, `List<>` and `Dictionary<,>` are unbound types.

To clarify the subtle distinction between an open type and an unbound type:

```
class Program {
   static void Main() { Test<int>(); }
   static void Test<T>() {
      Console.WriteLine(typeof(List<T>)); // Print out the type name
   }
}
```

If you run this snippet, it'll print out

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
```

which is the CLR name for `List<int>`. It's clear at runtime that the type argument is `System.Int32`. This makes `List<T>` a *bound* open type.

At runtime, you can use reflection to bind type arguments to unspecified type parameters of unbound generic types with the [`Type.MakeGenericType` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx):

```
Type unboundGenericList = typeof(List<>);
Type listOfInt = unboundGenericList.MakeGenericType(typeof(int));
if (listOfInt == typeof(List<int>))
     Console.WriteLine("Constructed a List<int> type.");
```

You can check whether a type is an unbound generic type (*generic type definition*) from which you can construct bound types with the [`Type.IsGenericTypeDefinition` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isgenerictypedefinition.aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Dictionary<,>).IsGenericTypeDefinition); // True
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Dictionary<int,int>).IsGenericTypeDefinition); // False
```

To get the unbound type from a constructed type at runtime, you can use the [`Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx).

```
Type listOfInt = typeof(List<int>);
Type list = listOfInt.GetGenericTypeDefinition(); // == typeof(List<>)
```

Note that for a generic type, you can either have a completely unbound type definition, or a completely bound definition. You can't bind some type parameters and leave others unbound. For instance, you can't have `Dictionary<int,>` or `Dictionary<,string>`.

Comment: +1 great info - I learned something new today. I knew that List<> was a generic type, but now I know the correct technical term.

Comment: You *can* actually partially close a generic type by providing a type argument that is itself an open generic type. However, this is a dead end.  The framework doesn't officially recognize this partial state, treating it as neither closed nor open, and so it doesn't allow you to do anything useful with it.

Comment: great explanation as to difference between open type and unbound type - didn't know before!

Comment: I agree with @ChrisAmmerman. For example the type `Dictionary<int,>` that you claim we can't have, is more or less constructed by `typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int), typeof(Dictionary<,>).GetGenericArguments()[1])`. But maybe you just meant to say that C# does not allow the syntax `Dictionary<int,>` so we have to create it manually like I did here.

Comment: ... And on the [doc page for `IsGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isgenerictype.aspx), in the *Examples* section's C# code, they regard in a more elegant way a type ``Base`2[System.String,V]`` where one type parameter is substituted with a concrete type and another one is substituted with a parameter `V`.

Answer (score 18):

An "open generic type" is just a generic type that doesn't yet have its type specified (e.g., `CargoCrate<T>`). It becomes "closed" once a concrete type has been assigned (e.g. `CargoCrate<Widget>`).

For example, say you have something like this:

```
public class Basket<T> {
  T[] basketItems;
}

public class PicnicBlanket<T> {
  Basket<T> picnicBasket;   // Open type here. We don't know what T is.
}

                                 // Closed type here: T is Food.
public class ParkPicnicBlanket : PicnicBlanket<Food> {
}
```

Here, `picnicBasket`'s type is open: nothing's yet been assigned to `T`. When you make a concrete PicnicBlanket with a specific type -- for example, by writing `PicnicBlanket<Food> p = new PicnicBlanket<Food>()` -- we now call it *closed*.

Answer (score 14):

Just to add:

`Dictionary<string, T>` (or more precisely `Dictionary<string,>`) is still an open type.

Example:

```
void Foo<T>(Dictionary<string,T> dic) { ... }
```

Comment: Upon looking up the spec, I'm seeing that you're right. I thought the "generic type definition" is the same thing as "open type" in the spec but apparently, the spec calls a type parameter and `List<T>` open types and the `List<>` an unbound type. Clarifying my answer. +1

Answer (score 11):

There are three kinds of generic types.  To make it short, in this (simplified) declaration:

```
public class Dictionary<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
```

- `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is an **unbounded generic type**.
- `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is, in this case, an **open constructed generic type**.  It has some type parameters, but they are already defined elsewhere (in Dictionary, in this case).
- `Dictionary<string, int>` would be a **closed constructed generic type**.