# What is the term for empty generic parameters <,> in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Language: generics, open/closed, bound/unbound, constructed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607033/c-sharp-language-generics-open-closed-bound-unbound-constructed)

While doing some stuff with reflection in C#, I've noticed that some types have the type definition e.g.

```
Foo<,>
```

What is the official term for this notation?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I wouldn't call this a duplicate. I'm asking "What is `Foo<,>` called?" whereas he's asking "What's an unbound generic type?" There's no way I would have found his question on Google without already knowing the name.

Comment: To my mind, that makes it a duplicate which should not be deleted.

Comment: a more closely related link: [if-at1-t2-is-a-template-for-actual-type-then-why-is-typeofa-allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220480/if-at1-t2-is-a-template-for-actual-type-then-why-is-typeofa-allowed?lq=1)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Type names which are missing generic parameters such as `List<>` are referred to as unbound generic types. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607033/c-sharp-language-generics-open-closed-bound-unbound-constructed) has a good summary of unbound generic types as well as some related terminology.

Depending on what context you are describing these types, some other terminology may be used. The C# specification uses the term "unbound generic type" to refer to something like `T<>`. The .Net framework seems to prefer the terms "generic type definition" (as [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13597178/124538) pointed out, see also [`Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx)) or "open generic type" (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172334.aspx) article).

Comment: Is *unbound generic types* a synonym of *generic type definition*?

Comment: @Bringer128 IMO, *type definition* is the source code which defines a type. So, I don't think they are synonyms.

Answer (score 3):

This is a type that represents a *generic type definition*:

```
 var genType = typeof(Foo<int,int>);
 var genTypeDef = genType.GetGenericTypeDefinition(); // Returns typeof(Foo<,>)
```

Comment: Is *generic type definition* a synonym of *unbound generic types*?

Comment: @Bringer128 The two are related: the generic type definition is the term used in the reflection to describe `System.Type` objects corresponding to unbounded generic types.