# .NET generics terminology - open/closed, unbound/constructed

Tags: .net, generics

.NET generics terminology is a bit ambiguous. Even worse - it seems to be used ambiguously and differently in different sources. What basically is not clear is relationships between these 4 terms (in relation to "Type"):

1. open
2. closed
3. unbound
4. constructed

I understand that `List<T>` is open and `List<int>` is closed. But what really is "constructed" and "unbound" in relation to open/closed types?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the [language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=DFBF523C-F98C-4804-AFBD-459E846B268E):

> **4.4 Constructed types**
>
> A generic type declaration, by itself,
> denotes an **unbound generic type** that
> is used as a “blueprint” to form many
> different types, by way of applying
> **type arguments**. The type arguments are
> written within angle brackets (< and> )
> immediately following the name of the generic type. A type that includes
> at least one type argument is called a
> **constructed type**. A constructed type
> can be used in most places in the
> language in which a type name can
> appear. An unbound generic type can
> only be used within a
> typeof-expression (§7.6.11).
> [...]
>
> **4.4.2 Open and closed types**
>
> All types can be classified as either
> **open types** or **closed types**. An open
> type is a type that involves type
> parameters. More specifically:
>
> • A
> type parameter defines an open type.
>
> • An array type is an open type if and
> only if its element type is an open
> type.
>
> •  A constructed type is an open
> type if and only if one or more of its
> type arguments is an open type. A
> constructed nested type is an open
> type if and only if one or more of its
> type arguments or the type arguments
> of its containing type(s) is an open
> type.
>
> A closed type is a type that is
> not an open type.
> [...]
>
> **4.4.3 Bound and unbound types**
>
> The term **unbound type** refers to a non-generic
> type or an unbound generic type. The
> term **bound type** refers to a
> non-generic type or a constructed
> type. An unbound type refers to the
> entity declared by a type declaration.
> An unbound generic type is not itself
> a type, and cannot be used as the type
> of a variable, argument or return
> value, or as a base type. The only
> construct in which an unbound generic
> type can be referenced is the typeof
> expression (§7.6.11).

---

Here's an example I thought of:

```
// Foo<T> is an unbound generic type.
class Foo<T> { .. } 

// Bar<K> is an unbound generic type.
// Its base-class Foo<K> is a constructed, open generic type.
class Bar<K> : Foo<K> { .. } 

// IntFoo is not a generic type.
// Its base-class Foo<int> is a constructed, closed generic type.
class IntFoo : Foo<int> { .. }
```

---

And here's an attempt to tie that in with the reflection API, using the relevant properties: `IsGenericType`, `IsGenericTypeDefinition` and `ContainsGenericParameters`

(These tests are not 100% predictive of each "kind" as per the language spec).

```
+----------+---------------------+-----------+--------------+-------------------+
|   Name   |        Kind         | IsGenType | IsGenTypeDef | ContainsGenParams |
+----------+---------------------+-----------+--------------+-------------------+
| Foo<>    | Unbound             | TRUE      | TRUE         | TRUE              |
| Foo<>*   | Constructed, open   | TRUE      | FALSE        | TRUE              |
| Foo<int> | Constructed, closed | TRUE      | FALSE        | FALSE             |
| IntFoo   | Not generic         | FALSE     | FALSE        | FALSE             |
+----------+---------------------+-----------+--------------+-------------------+
* = Bar<>'s base type.
```

Comment: Also see the *Examples* section of the [doc page for `IsGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isgenerictype.aspx). For the new property `IsConstructedGenericType` see a [thread I just started](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796119/).

Comment: And see [What exactly is an “open generic type” in .NET? (duplicate)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173107/).