# Will IsConstructedGenericType always be the negation of IsGenericTypeDefinition, for a generic type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, types

The documentation of the instance property [`Type.IsConstructedGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isconstructedgenerictype.aspx) is unclear or misleading.

I tried the following code to find the actual behavior of this and related properties:

```
// create list of types to use later in a Dictionary<,>
var li = new List<Type>();

// two concrete types:
li.Add(typeof(int));
li.Add(typeof(string));

// the two type parameters from Dictionary<,>
li.Add(typeof(Dictionary<,>).GetGenericArguments()[0]);
li.Add(typeof(Dictionary<,>).GetGenericArguments()[1]);

// two unrelated type parameters
li.Add(typeof(Func<,,,>).GetGenericArguments()[1]);
li.Add(typeof(EventHandler<>).GetGenericArguments()[0]);

// run through all possibilities
foreach (var first in li)
{
    foreach (var second in li)
    {
        var t = typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(first, second);
        Console.WriteLine(t);
        Console.WriteLine(t.IsGenericTypeDefinition);
        Console.WriteLine(t.IsConstructedGenericType);
        Console.WriteLine(t.ContainsGenericParameters);
    }
}
```

The code runs through a Cartesian product consisting of 36 types `t`.

Results: For 32 types (all but the 4 combinations `Dictionary<int, int>`, `Dictionary<int, string>`, `Dictionary<string, int>`, `Dictionary<string, string>`), the value of `ContainsGenericParameters` was true.

For 35 types, `IsGenericTypeDefinition` was false while `IsConstructedGenericType` was true. For the last type, namely (unsurprisingly):

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue]
```

the `IsGenericTypeDefinition` was true and `IsConstructedGenericType` was false.

**Can I conclude that, for a generic type, the value of `IsConstructedGenericType` is always the opposite (negation) of `IsGenericTypeDefinition`?**

(The documentation seems to claim that `IsConstructedGenericType` is instead the opposite of `ContainsGenericParameters`, but we clearly exhibited a lot of counterexamples to that.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes this is correct. Assuming that the `Type` in question is a generic type, exactly one of `IsGenericTypeDefinition` or `IsConstructedGenericType` is true. We can easily from the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) for `RuntimeType` (which is the concrete implementation of `Type` you get when you do `GetType()` or `typeof`) why this is the case:

```
public override bool IsConstructedGenericType 
{
    get { return IsGenericType && !IsGenericTypeDefinition; } 
}
```

Comment: @ChristopherKing I won't deny that the Reflection API handles partially constructed types very poorly.