# Can't figure out how to get this DI stuff going

Tags: c#, ninject-2

Ok, I feel like a total idiot. I have read the docs and still cant get this working with Ninject.

```
 public class ContextAdapter:IDbSetProvider
{
    private readonly IContextFactory _contextFactory;
    #region Implementation of IDbSetProvider

    public ContextAdapter(IContextFactory contextFactory)
    {
        this._contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }

    public IDbSet<TEntity> CreateDBSet<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        var context = _contextFactory.Create();
        return context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

As you can see I am need to inject the contructor for the class above. Well, it is not going so well.
Help!! before I go back to writing perl code. Kidding!! LOl

Thoughts folks?

Comment: Yes it is a factory. Not abstract just a plain ol factory.

Comment: kernel.Bind<IContextFactory>()
                 .To<ContextAdapter>()
                 .WithConstructorArgument(IContextFactory, _contextFactory);

Comment: This does not even compile, what am I missing?

Comment: I am following the tutorial at http://stefanoricciardi.com/2011/01/21/ninject-mini-tutorial-part-1/

Comment: Why do you try to pass interface `IContextFactory` as an argument to `WithConstructorArgument`, you can't just pass an interface declaration. Should there be `.WithConstructorArgument("contextFactory", _contextFactory)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class `ContextAdapter` does not implement `IContextFactory`. Do you have a class like `class Factory : IContextFactory`? That is what you are missing here. Then you can bind it `kernel.Bind<IContextFactory>.To<Factory>()` and Ninject will create that type for you when you request an object or when it needs to fulfill a contract. I think your confusion comes from the binding syntax. You are, in general, not binding parameters together, you are binding interfaces to concrete implementations. Here is a quick example:

```
Bind<IEngine>.To<GasEngine>();
Bind<ICar>.To<Sedan>();

class Sedan : ICar
{
    public Sedan(IEngine engine) { }
}

// ...

kernel.Get<ICar>(); // get me a new car
```

When you ask Ninject for `ICar`, it will fulfill it with what was bound, `Sedan`. `Sedan` requires an `IEngine` in its constructor, which Ninject will fulfill with `GasEngine` since that is what was bound.

Comment: So in order to inject the dependency to satisfy the constructor the class has to inherit from IcontextFactory? Interesting, I was thinking about the logic behind all of this a bit whack then.

Comment: What if I put the [Inject] Attribute in like so: [Inject]
        public ContextAdapter(IContextFactory contextFactory)
        {
            this._contextFactory = contextFactory;
        }

Comment: You still need to bind a concrete implementation of `IContextFactory`. `kernel.Bind<IContextFactory>.To<ContextAdapter>()` is wrong.

Comment: The `[Inject]` attribute on a constructor is only used if you have more than one constructor in your class and you want Ninject to use a specific one. You can also apply it to properties to have them injected.

Comment: well the docs must be incorrect then. http://www.docstoc.com/docs/31783175/What-is-Ninject or I am reading it worng :) If ninject sees the [Inject] attribute it will try to activate an object for each of the parameters

Comment: That is true. But that very document also says that if you have a single contructor, `[Inject]` is optional.

Comment: Yeps, I am now at page 53 and reading about how you don't have to use Inject and should use by convention lol... God I love open source

Comment: So essentially having the factory is not needed if I can use ninject conditional's for Dbcontext. Considering that is really the only dependency I am trying to resolve

Comment: Have a look at `ToMethod` as a binding target. Your `CreateDbSet` method could be called here if you `IDataSet<>` to it. For example: `kernel.Bind(typeof(IDataSet<>)).ToMethod(ctx => CreateDbSet)`. You might need a bit of experimentation to get it working, but it would eliminate the need for your `ContextAdapter` class. If `typeof(IDataSet<>)` looks strange to you, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173107/net-what-exactly-is-an-open-generic-type for info on open generics.

Comment: funny how we look back at the things we have posted. LOL