# Is a generic type MyType<,> actually a type?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, mef

I have some confusion with this that arose from messing around with exporting generic types in MEF

I noticed:

```
new Dictionary<string,bool>().GetType() == typeof(Dictionary<,>)
false
new Dictionary<string,bool>().GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dictionary<,>)
true
```

Yet Dictionary<,> itself is not considered a ‘type’ as this will actually generate a compile error:

```
new Dictionary<string,bool> as Dictionary<,>
Type expected
new Dictionary<string,bool> is Dictionary<,>
Type expected
```

So my question is, is Dictionary<,> actually a type? Does .NET treat generic types differently than non-generic types?

Now in MEF I can export a generic class as

```
[Export(typeof(MyGenericClass<,>))]
```

And this would satisfy an import requirement like

```
[Import]
public MyGenericClass<string, long> Instance { get; set; }
```

I'm confused about the type-system's rules here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [What exactly is an “open generic type”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2173115/880990). What you are referring to is called an *unbound generic type* and is explained in the same [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2173115/880990). An *unbound generic type* is actually a type, however it can only be used within a `typeof()` expression. Note: Unlike C# Java allows expressions like `List<?>`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MyType<,> is a type.
It's a "open generic" Type, See [What exactly is an "open generic type" in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173107/net-what-exactly-is-an-open-generic-type)