# calling one common method in multiple web services methods and using generic method

Tags: c#

I recently asked a question about calling methods on generic types in C#: [calling method in template in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183528/calling-method-in-template-in-c-sharp)

The problem I have is that I cannot manipulate the types I want to create a generic function for. The types are SoapClients of a few WebServices that have the same methods. Is there any solution that would let me avoid copying the code?

Comment: I really don't understand what are you saying. Also, there doesn't seem to any actual question in your post.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have several types that you cannot change, that don't share any interface but have some method in common. And you want to write a single method that invokes this common method for any of the types.

To do this, I think you have two options:

1. Create a wrapper for each class, that does implement a common interface. You would then use that interface in your method and give it the wrapper as an argument.
2. Use `dynamic` to invoke the method. Using `dynamic`, you don't have to implement any interface, but it also means you are losing all compile-time type checking (and autocompletion).