# T4 template typeOf(List<>) results in error but works in C# class

Tags: c#, t4

Hi I seem to be having some problem on a T4 template.Here is my code:

```
  private void ResolveComplexType(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        var property = propertyInfo.PropertyType;

        if (property.IsGenericType && property.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
        {
            var argumentType = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            PrintPropertiesInfo(argumentType);
        }
        else
        {
            PrintPropertiesInfo(property);
        }
    }
```

I am getting Identifier_Literal expected error on `typeof(List<>))`.I tested the exact same method on a C# class and it worked perfectly.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

**EDIT**

This is the error:

> Error 2   Identifier_Literal expected

Comment: List<?> -- ?=Some Class like String, int or any other class. You are missing that here

Comment: @MehbubeArman that's called an [open generic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173107/what-exactly-is-an-open-generic-type-in-net). The code is OK.

Comment: Can you try just this: `<# bool x = typeof(List<int>).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>); #>` and tell us whether that works?

Comment: Have you perhaps redefined what `List` means?

Comment: can you post the exact error message?

Comment: I have tryed this expression <# bool x = typeof(List<int>).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>); #> and I get the same error at List<>

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?  My 2012 version compiles your code fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this sample code I get no errors in T4 generation and compilation. Try to compare with your code.

```
<#@ template inherits="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.ModelingTextTransformation" language="C#v3.5" debug="true" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Core.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Windows.Forms.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #> 
<#
   // insert your template code here the tempalte code will be syntaxhighlighted 
   // and you will have intellisense for all namespaces in the full edition
   string Greeting = "Hello";
#>
// This is the output code from your template
// you only get syntax-highlighting here - not intellisense
namespace MyNameSpace{
using System.Collections.Generic;
  class MyGeneratedClass{
     static void main (string[] args){
     if(typeof(List<>).ToString() == "yadayadayada" ){System.Console.WriteLine("isYadayadayada");}
       System.Console.WriteLine("<#= typeof(List<>) #>");
     }
  }
}

<#+
  // Insert any template procedures here
  void foo(){
    System.Console.WriteLine(typeof(List<>));
}
#>
```