# Check if an object is a type of collection, regardless of what Type that collection is of?

Tags: c#

I can check for a single type by using

```
if (e.PropertyType == typeof(EntityCollection<Search_SearchCodes>))
```

But but I really want to avoid all objects that are `EntityCollections`

```
if (e.PropertyType == typeof(EntityCollection))
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Servy: IIRC (which I rarely do), `EntityCollection<T>` is `sealed`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by confirming that the type is a generic type, and its [generic type definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx) is equal to the `EntityCollection<>` [open generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173107/what-exactly-is-an-open-generic-type-in-net).

```
var type = e.PropertyType;
var isEntityCollection = type.IsGenericType && 
    type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityCollection<>);
```

Comment: Excellent, that works great. Also, it never occurred to me that you can use multiple conditionals when assigning a boolean, so I learned two cool things, thanks!