# Non-generic class implementation of generic interface is not inherited

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

If I have this code:

```
public interface IThing<T> where T : class
{
    // ...
}

public class BaseThing<T> : IThing<T> where T : class
{
    // ...
}

public class ThingA : BaseThing<string>
{
    // ...
}

public class ThingB : BaseThing<Uri>
{
    // ...
}
```

This code fails:

```
List<IThing<object>> thingList = new List<IThing<object>>();

thingList.Add(new ThingA());
thingList.Add(new ThingB());
```

Even though `ThingA` (indirectly) inherits from (and should be an instance of) `IThing<T>`. Why? Is `ThingA`/`ThingB` not an instance of `IThing<T>`?

Comment: Read up on covariance and contravariance.  (I don't know enough to answer the question other than knowing that these concepts are related.)

Comment: Note that all "instances" of `IThing<T>` like `IThing<string>`, `IThing<Uri>`, `IThing<object>` are siblings - there is no inheritance relation between them. There is also no inheritance relation with `IThing<T>` which is really totally different thing (and also different from `IThing<>` - [open generic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173107/what-exactly-is-an-open-generic-type-in-net)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would require your interface to be covariant.  For details, see [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx).

In this case, you can make this work by using:

```
// Add out here
public interface IThing<out T> where T : class
{
}
```

Note that this does place limitations on the interface and what you can do with it, however, as it requires that the type `T` in the interface be used only as a method return type within the interface, and not used as a type of formal method parameters.

If this is not viable, another option is to create a non-generic `IThing` interface, and have `IThing<T>` implement `IThing`.  You could then use `List<IThing>` for your collection.

Comment: Yeah, I have properties defined in the interface that use `T` (like `List<T>`), so this won't work. Is there anything else I can change about the design that will make this work, or should I look at re-architecting this?

Comment: @SpikeX You'd need to rearchitect it a bit.  One option is to make a non-generic `IThing` interface, and have `IThing<T>` implement it.  You could then create a `List<IThing>` and use that...

Comment: Creating the non-generic interface to complement the generic one did the trick. The code compiles, and even better, MEF is working again, too. Thanks!