# Deserializing JSON to a generic interface property

Tags: c#, .net, json, generics, serialization

I have a generic class which contains a public property which is a generic interface of the same type as the parent class.  Example code below.

```
public interface IExample<T>
{
    T Value { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Example<T> : IExample<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class Parent<T>
{
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public IExample<T> ExampleItem { get; set; }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public Parent<int> IntParent { get; set; }
}
```

I am using JSON.net to serialize the `MainClass` object which can contain many `Parent<T>` objects.  `Parent<T>` can be any generic with no type constraints.  However, I cannot seem to deserialize the resulting JSON in a generic fashion.

I attempted to create a `JsonConverter` for the JSON.net deserializer, but I cannot find a way to apply it generically.  Example `JsonConverter` below.

```
public class InterfaceJsonConverter<TInterface, TImplementation> : JsonConverter where TImplementation : TInterface, new()
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (typeof(TInterface) == objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return serializer.Deserialize<TImplementation>(reader);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```

The above converter would allow an attribute to be placed on the `ExampleItem` property of the `Parent<T>` class like:

```
public class Parent<T>
{
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(InterfaceJsonConverter<IExample<T>, Example<T>>))]
    public IExample<T> ExampleItem { get; set; }
}
```

But c# does not let you have generic type references in attributes (because of the nature of attributes and reflection).  The only solution I have come up with so far is to add a new `InterfaceJsonConverter` for each expected type T manually to the serializer before calling the `Deserialize()` method.  However, this limits the possible types of `Parent<T>` since each type needs to be added manually if it can be deserialized.

Is there any way to deserialize this in a generic way?  Is there another approach I should be taking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done, albeit indirectly, by passing the [open generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173107/what-exactly-is-an-open-generic-type-in-net) `typeof(Example<>)` to an appropriate `JsonConverter` as a constructor argument, then inside `ReadJson()` constructing an appropriate closed generic type by assuming the `objectType` passed in has the same generic parameters as the desired concrete closed generic type.

Note also that, as long as the converter is applied directly to a property using [`[JsonConverter(Type,Object[])]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute__ctor_1.htm), it is not necessary for the converter to know the interface type, since [`CanConvert()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanConvert.htm) will not be called.  `CanConvert()` is only called when the converter is in the [`JsonSerializer.Converters`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Converters.htm) list.

Thus your converter becomes:

```
public class InterfaceToConcreteGenericJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    readonly Type GenericTypeDefinition;

    public InterfaceToConcreteGenericJsonConverter(Type genericTypeDefinition)
    {
        if (genericTypeDefinition == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.GenericTypeDefinition = genericTypeDefinition;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    Type MakeGenericType(Type objectType)
    {
        if (!GenericTypeDefinition.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
            return GenericTypeDefinition;
        try
        {
            var parameters = objectType.GetGenericArguments();
            return GenericTypeDefinition.MakeGenericType(parameters);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Wrap the reflection exception in something more useful.
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unable to construct concrete type from generic {0} and desired type {1}", GenericTypeDefinition, objectType), ex);
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return serializer.Deserialize(reader, MakeGenericType(objectType));
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Apply it as follows:

```
public class Parent<T>
{
    public string ParentName { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(InterfaceToConcreteGenericJsonConverter), new object[] { typeof(Example<>) })]
    public IExample<T> ExampleItem { get; set; }
}
```

To apply such a converter with parameters to collection items, use [`JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemConverterType`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm) and [`JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemConverterParameters`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterParameters.htm), e.g.:

```
public class Parent<T>
{
    public string ParentName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(InterfaceToConcreteGenericJsonConverter), ItemConverterParameters = new object[] { typeof(Example<>) })]
    public List<IExample<T>> ExampleList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This worked!  Didn't think about using reflection inside of the converter - great solution.  Thank you!