# Reflection Get List<> from List<T> (Container type from generic container type)

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, collections, .net-4.5

I have a peculiar situation where in one of reflectors I can get different types of containers that I need to reinflate (like make clones of). This started happening when new type of container was introduced (`ObservableCollection<T>`)

Within cloning mechanism what I have found was this:

```
if (property.PropertyType.FullName.Contains(ReflectorResources.ListName) || property.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("ConcurrentBag"))
{
    var listElementType = property.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
    var newList = (property.PropertyType.FullName.Contains(ReflectorResources.IncidentListName))
         ? Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Definitions.Session.Products.Motor.IncidentList<>).MakeGenericType(listElementType))
         : property.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("ConcurrentBag") ? Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ConcurrentBag<>).MakeGenericType(listElementType)) : Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(listElementType));    
    var oneItem = Activator.CreateInstance(listElementType);
}
```

So I tried to rewrite it like:

```
if (new[] { ".Collections." }.Any(o => property.PropertyType.FullName.Contains(o)))
{
    var listElementType = property.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
    var listType = property.PropertyType;
    var constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(listElementType);
    var newList = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListType);
    var oneItem = Activator.CreateInstance(listElementType);
}
```

however it blows up on the line: `var constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(listElementType);` with error

> System.InvalidOperationException : Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true.

My guess is that I need to extract `List<>` type from `List<Something>`...

**How do I get container type from generic container type?**

Comment: quick comment: Why don't you just call CreateInstance on property.PropertyType?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
var listElementType = property.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
var listType = property.PropertyType;
var constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(listElementType);
```

Try this:

```
Type listElementType = property.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
Type constructedListType;
if (! property.PropertyType.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
    constructedListType = property.PropertyType;
else
{
    // Depending on where your property comes from
    // This should not work in the case the property type is List<T>
    // How listElementType should allow you to instantiate your type ?
    var listType = property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(listElementType);
}
```

---

*I was also saying you should look at `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` method, but there was already the AakashM's answer before I finished to write this.

Then you should take a look at his answer.*

Answer (score 1):

I am going to quote from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173107/what-exactly-is-an-open-generic-type-in-net/2173115#2173115), which probably answers any question you have about reflection and generics:

> To get the unbound type from a constructed type at runtime, you can
>   use the [`Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx).
>
> ```
> Type listOfInt = typeof(List<int>);
> Type list = listOfInt.GetGenericTypeDefinition(); // == typeof(List<>)
> ```