# How to know if an object is a generic list

Tags: list, delphi, generics

How can I know if an object (TObject) is a generic `TList<T>`.

The object I get can be a `TList<TWhateverObject>` or just a TWhateverObject

Can also be a `TList<THelloWorld>`

In my code I won't use this:

```
  If (oObject is TList<TWhateverObject>) or
     (oObject is TList<THelloWorld>)

  then begin
    oObject.Free;
  end;
```

But if possible more like this:

```
  If (oObject.IsList)
  then begin
    oObject.Free;
  end;
```

Is there some function in Delphi for that or must I create a helper for TObject (IsList) that search in the RTTI if property add, clear, items, count exist in the object.

Comment: Tuo can try with the `is` keyword like `if (Sender is TObject) then`. Your question is not very specific, do you mean a TList?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you cannot use the `is` operator here since you are checking if the class is any specialization of a generic type (`TList<T>` in your case).

Since Delphi does not have the concept of open generic types (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173107/what-exactly-is-an-open-generic-type-in-net) about them in .Net) it is not quite as simple.

However you can use some tricks and analyze the typeinfo/classname. So in order to check if your instance is a `TList<something>` you just have to check if the classname matches `TList<*>` or if it inherits from a class where it does.

In Spring4D we need this quite a few times so I added this functionality to our RTTI helpers.

There it looks like this (add `Spring.Reflection.pas` to the uses):

```
TType.GetType(oObject).IsGenericTypeOf('TList<>');
```