# Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(string) returns null

Tags: c#

Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(string) returns null

I think this is because string is a reference type, should this not work though for built in types which string is?

To Expand on my question,
If you call

```
Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(int)
```

You get nothing back as int is not nullable

if you call

```
 Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(int?)
```

a result is returned as it is a nullable type

But a string by default is nullable as it is a reference type, but is also a built in type so I was expecting

```
Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(string)
```

to return something as it is nullable

Comment: It returns "The type argument of the nullableType parameter, if the nullableType parameter is a closed generic nullable type; otherwise, null."

Comment: Even if it "worked", what would you like it to return? What would be the "underlying" type of `String`? You can write a method that returns `T` if `T` is `Nullable<T>` and `T` if `T` is a reference type, but `GetUnderlyingType` wouldn't be a good name for it.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], I don't want to guess what you actually mean by that pseudo-code.

Comment: The method behaves exactly as it is documented to behave. I don't understand your question. What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So according to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype(v=vs.110).aspx) for Nullable.GetUnderlyingType, the return type for it is:

"The type argument of the nullableType parameter, if the nullableType parameter is a closed generic nullable type; otherwise, null."

So what is a closed generic nullable type? A great explanation can be found here from Mehrdad([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173107/what-exactly-is-an-open-generic-type-in-net)).

From his post:

> "All types can be classified as either open types or closed types. An
>   open type is a type that involves type parameters. More specifically:
>
> A type parameter defines an open type. An array type is an open type
>   if and only if its element type is an open type. A constructed type is
>   an open type if and only if one or more of its type arguments is an
>   open type. A constructed nested type is an open type if and only if
>   one or more of its type arguments or the type arguments of its
>   containing type(s) is an open type. A closed type is a type that is
>   not an open type."

So for an example:

Closed generic nullable type = `List<string>`

Open generic type = `List<T>`

**UPDATED:**

Thanks to Kiziu's comments and clarification I have updated my answer.

[Nullable.GetUnderlyingType](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,132)

The only case where a value other than null will be returned is 
when the type is of typeof(Nullable<>). 
Nullable<> is a struct, which means it cannot inherited. So since string isn't of type Nullable<>, it will return null. Where as data types like int?, double? that are of type Nullable<> will return their underlying types.

Comment: `If it was of type List<string>, it would return type string` is not true. Have a look here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,132 . What the method does is to check if type implements `Nullable<T>`, `List<T>` does not. Description on MSDN is not accurate enough and too liberal with phrase *nullable type*.

Comment: @Kiziu Aren't all objects with type parameters of type Nullable<T>?

Comment: I assume that by `objects with type parameters` you mean closed generic types. No, they are not. `Nullable<T>` is a struct, which means it cannot be inherited.

Comment: @Kiziu, yes I did, you are correct. Thank you so much for the clarification, I will update the answer.