# How to create and iterate over a method group list

Tags: c#

I have a series of generic methods that accept a type to run.  For instance:

```
db.CreateTable<MyClassName>();
```

I want to be able to create a list of classes and then iterate over the list like:

```
foreach(var class in classList)
{
    db.CreateTable<class>();
    db.CheckStatus<class>();

    // ... etc
}
```

VS says the parameter is a `method group`.  I googled this and docs say this is a delegate.  How do i create a list of delegates pointing to my classes that I can then iterate over and use as reference in call to generic method?

Comment: you cannot (simply) vary the type bound to a generic at run time, its a compile time thing. Does this need to be a generic, why not a method that simply accepts a Type as an arg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer makes an assumption I just realized might not be valid: I am assuming that `classList` is a `IEnumerable<Type>`.  If that is incorrect, my answer will need to be revised.

It needs to be something *like* this.

```
var fn = db.GetType().GetMethod("CheckStatus");

foreach (var cls in classList)
{
    var fn2 = fn.MakeGenericMethod(cls);
    fn2.Invoke(db, null);
}
```

Okay, what's going on here.  We get a reference to the method on the `db` object called "CheckStatus".  If there are overloads of that method, you'll need to use one of the overloads of [`GetMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.typeinfo.getmethod?view=netstandard-1.6) to get it.

Then, we make it a closed generic method.  So in the first part, we get a method `CheckStatus<T>`, where `T` is not specified.  This is an *open* generic.  You need to fill in the generic with your type information.  That is what `MakeGenericMethod` does.  In effect, it gives you `CheckStatus<cls>`.  You can then invoke this method on `db`.

For more information on open/closed generics, see: [What exactly is an “open generic type” in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173107/what-exactly-is-an-open-generic-type-in-net)