# Register Generic Repository raise Error "The number of generic arguments provided doesn't equal the arity"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I got this error:

> ArgumentException: The number of generic arguments provided doesn't
>   equal the arity of the generic type definition. Parameter name:
>   instantiation

```
public class EfCoreRepository<TContext, TEntity> : IEfCoreRepository<TEntity>
            where TContext : IEfCoreDbContext
            where TEntity : class
            {
        ....
        }
```

> Here is the interface

```
public interface IEfCoreRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
```

where I register it like that

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IEfCoreRepository<>), typeof(EfCoreRepository<,>));
```

Comment: I don't think you can register an [open type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173107/what-exactly-is-an-open-generic-type-in-net). You can't instantiate an open type, so why would you want to register it?

Comment: I think it's should be ```services.AddScoped(typeof(IEfCoreRepository<>), typeof(EfCoreRepository<>));``` right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the interface to be

```
public interface IEfCoreRepository<TContext, TEntity> 
         where TContext : IEfCoreDbContext
         where TEntity : class
```

and then register it like this

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IEfCoreRepository<,>), typeof(EfCoreRepository<,>));
```