# Correct way to check if a type is Nullable

Tags: c#, generics, nullable

In order to check if a `Type` ( `propertyType` ) is nullable, I'm using:

```
bool isNullable =  "Nullable`1".Equals(propertyType.Name)
```

Is there some way that avoid using magic strings ?

Comment: Check if a type is `Nullable<T>`? If so, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374651/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-nullable

Comment: This question is not duplicated. It asks for if type is nullable (not object is nullable)

Answer (score 529, accepted):

Absolutely - use [`Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype.aspx):

```
if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType) != null)
{
    // It's nullable
}
```

Note that this uses the non-generic static class [`System.Nullable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs5xdbk8.aspx) rather than the generic struct `Nullable<T>`.

Also note that that will check whether it represents a *specific* (closed) nullable value type... it won't work if you use it on a *generic* type, e.g.

```
public class Foo<T> where T : struct
{
    public Nullable<T> Bar { get; set; }
}

Type propertyType = typeof(Foo<>).GetProperty("Bar").PropertyType;
// propertyType is an *open* type...
```

Comment: Looks like you've found a very interesting disagreement between the specification (your link in the first line) and the actual behavior. For your `propertyType` object from the last line is a counter-example. What I mean is that `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType)` does **not** return null (it returns your `T`) although `propertyType` is an _open_ generic type (`propertyType.ContainsGenericParameters`). I experimented a bit, and it looks like an open generic type with ``Nullable`1`` is OK _unless_ the type parameter is exactly the `T` from `typeof(Nullable<>).GetGenericArguments()[0]`.

Comment: What do you mean by "it returns your T"? This sounds like it's worth adding as a new question, with a short but complete example.

Comment: @JonSkeet I would have expected `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType( typeof( string ) ) != null` to return true.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @ELMOJO Why would you expect that? String isn't a nullable value type.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, I realized that about 15 minutes after I typed it.  One of those momentary lapses in reasoning.

Comment: @JonSkeet string is definitely nullable

Comment: @BojidarStanchev: It's not a nullable *value* type though. (And in C# 8 with nullable reference types enabled, it's not even a nullable type :) Then again, what would I know - I use `var` all the time in C#, contrary to the implied advice in your profile. Doesn't seem to be hurting my career so far.

Comment: What about `default(T) == null`? Are there any pitfalls with that assumption?

Comment: @Paul: It depends on what you're trying to achieve. The question was written long before nullable reference types existed, so I'm loathe to speculate further, to be honest.

Answer (score 77):

Use the following code to determine whether a Type object represents a Nullable type. Remember that this code always returns false if the Type object was returned from a call to GetType.

```
if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)) {…}
```

explained at the below MSDN link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366789.aspx

Moreover, there is a similar discussion at this SO QA:

[How to check if an object is nullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374651/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-nullable)

Comment: Thank you for the link to the other SO question. There is a mountain of information on the other question.

Comment: It would be good to add `!type.IsGenericTypeDefinition` is well. Else this will return true for `typeof(Nullable<>)`, which may or may not be desired, just saying