# Check if property is either of type or it's nullable type

Tags: c#, reflection

I am currently checking if a property type is either a DateTime or a nullable DateTime like this:

```
if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) || prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
```

Can anyone please tell me if I can somehow condense this into a single statement by checking the underlying type?

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939939/correct-way-to-check-if-a-type-is-nullable). Answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple sollution: `typeof(DateTime?).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType)`. This will be **true** for `DateTime?` or `DateTime` and **false** for others.

Comment: Thanks Vasily, though I want to true if it is EITHER DateTime OR DateTime? I don't want to know if it is nullable or not.

Comment: @CameronForward, I see now. Can you check new version?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
if (prop.PropertyType.UnderlyingSystemType==typeof(DateTime))
```

...

Comment: Thanks Mohammad but this doesn't pick up the nullable struct unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Your code goes here
         DateTime? nullableDate = null;

         bool output = CheckNull.IsNullable(nullableDate); // false

         Console.WriteLine(output );
    }

 public static class CheckNull
 {
   public static bool IsNullable<T>(T t) { return false; }
   public static bool IsNullable<T>(T? t) where T : struct { return true; }
 }
}
```

output : `True`