# Get Func types from a List of Expression<Func>

Tags: c#

I have the following list on a class:

```
public class Mapper {

  public List<Expression> Expressions { get; set; } = new List<Expression>();

}
```

I know that all Expressions will be:

```
Expression<Func<InType, OutType>>
```

The problem is that the InType and OutType vary in the list ...

I tried to define something like but it does not compile.

```
Expression<Func<,>>
```

Later on I will need to go through each Expression and get the input and output types of the function.

Is this possible?

Comment: `List<Expression>>` is that a typo?

Comment: If InType and OutType vary, you might want to reconsider if you should keep those in the same list. Else, maybe InType and OutType could have the same base class or implement a common interface maybe.

Comment: Why not declare the list as `List<LambdaExpression>`? Then you can also get the Parameters (i.e. the InType) and the returned type (i.e. the OutType) programmatically

Comment: @bassfader `LambdaExpression` *is* an (inherits from) Expression = both share the `Parameters` and `ReturnType` properties.

Comment: @marsze I know that `Expression` is the base-type (of all expressions). But the `Parameters` and the `ReturnType` properties are defined by the LambdaExpression and are not part of the `Expression` base class, they are defined by the `LambdaExpression` class (see [this link on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: @bassfader You're right, that was not clear. We are talking about `Expression<TDelegate>` here of course which inherits from `LambaExpression`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @bassfader I updated my answer, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes there is only one in-parameter:

```
public List<LambdaExpression> Expressions { get; set; } = new List<LambdaExpression>();

foreach (LambdaExpression expression in Expressions)
{
    var inType = expression.Paramters[0].Type;
    var outType = expresssion.ReturnType;
}
```

Depending on the use case it would be best to make the in and out type have a common base class or share an interface, which would make checking for their type unnecessary.

EDIT:

Only LambdaExpressions have the `ReturnType` and `Parameters` properties. `Expression<TDelegate>` inherits from `LambdaExpression`.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not generally possible.

A type like `Expression<Func<_,_>>` is called a higher kinded type. The C# language has no way to express such types.

Comment: As a comment, I did not answer the (unasked) question of what to do instead. But what you can do is get the parameter and return types from the expression, and cast it to the proper expression. It's ugly, but it'll work.

Comment: Higher kinder type.... open type... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173107/what-exactly-is-an-open-generic-type-in-net also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607033/c-sharp-language-generics-open-closed-bound-unbound-constructed

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code

```
            List<Expression> list = new List<Expression>();

            var typePairs = list.OfType<LambdaExpression>().Select(x =>
                new
                {
                    inType = x.Parameters[0].Type,
                    outType = x.ReturnType
                });
```

Comment: What is the difference between using LambdaExpression and Expression?

Comment: @MiguelMoura There are lots of expressions that aren't lambdas.

Comment: @MiguelMoura Type Expression doesnt have Parameters and ReturnType. It is from LambdaExpression

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are willing to do some reflection. It is not possible by using only compile time types, but with reflection you can extract the types at runtime.

Drawbacks are:

- You have to ensure that the list only contains `Expression<Func<In, Out>>`s, and not other type expressions. (cannot be checked in compile time)
- It's slow

Example code:

```
class Program
{
    public static void ConsumeExpressions(List<LambdaExpression> exprs)
    {
        var consumerMethod = typeof(Program).GetMethod("ConsumeExpression", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        foreach (var expr in exprs)
        {
            var inType = expr.Parameters[0].Type;
            var outType = expr.ReturnType;
            var genericMethod = consumerMethod.MakeGenericMethod(inType, outType);
            genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { expr });
        }
    }

    public static void ConsumeExpression<TInType, TOutType>(Expression<Func<TInType, TOutType>> expr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in: {0}, out: {1}, {2}", typeof(TInType).Name, typeof(TOutType).Name, expr);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsumeExpressions(new List<LambdaExpression>
        {
            (Expression<Func<int, string>>)(i => ""),
            (Expression<Func<string, int>>)(s => 0)
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Suggest using `LambdaExpression`s based on Brahim's post, so the reflection part gets shorter and clearer.

Answer (score 0):

All types derive from object... you easily use object but will lose the type safety you desire.

Perhaps define an interface IParameter which defines the semantics of your logic e.g. InType, OutType, HasInputValue, HasOutputValue.

Use the interface implementation to solve the problem.

Perhaps define a Number or NumberResult class which implements that interface and use it or the interface as the type exposed on the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here a  full example that can help you

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Expression>  expressions =  new List<Expression>();
        Expression <Func<string,int>> func = a => a.Length;

        expressions.Add(func);
        foreach (var expression in expressions)
        {
            LambdaExpression lmdExpression = expression  as LambdaExpression;
            if (lmdExpression!=null)
            {    
                //get  all params 
                 List<string>   paramsList  = new List<string>();
                foreach (var parameterExpression in lmdExpression.Parameters)
                {                        paramsList.Add(parameterExpression.Type.ToString());  
                }
                var returnedType = lmdExpression.ReturnType.ToString(); 
                //and  here you can use a big switch  to  invoke your needed expression                 
            }
        }        
        Console.ReadLine();     
    }
}
```

***Why using Expression and LambdaExpression?***

Because `LambdaExpression` is an abstract class from which derives `Expression<TDelegate>` and since you don't know which type of `Func<T,T>` you are using you have to use a base class

Comment: Why using Expression and LambdaExpression?

Answer (score -2):

**Update:** Thanks to all the colleagues and their comments. Replaced my original answer.

First thing, you absolutely don't need `Expression` to make this work, because bottom line, it's a type locator with a twist. Take a look at the following implementation:

```
public class FuncMapper
{
    Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _funcs = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

    public void Register<TIn, TOut>(Func<TIn, TOut> func)
    {
        _funcs.Add(func.GetType(), func);
    }

    public TOut Execute<TIn, TOut>(TIn param)
    {
        return ((Func<TIn, TOut>)_funcs[typeof(Func<TIn, TOut>)])(param);
    }
}
```

Then using it is a simple as this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FuncMapper funcMapper = new FuncMapper();

        funcMapper.Register<string, string>(DoString);
        funcMapper.Register<int, int>(DoInt);

        Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", funcMapper.Execute<string, string>("Test"));
        Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", funcMapper.Execute<int, int>(10));

        Console.Read();
    }

    static string DoString(string param)
    {
        return param;
    }

    static int DoInt(int param)
    {
        return param;
    }
}
```

**Update2:** If you really do need expression for whatever reason, you can change the `Register` method in the following manner:

```
public void Register<TIn, TOut>(Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> expression)
{
    Func<TIn, TOut> func = expression.Compile();

    _funcs.Add(func.GetType(), func);
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
funcMapper.Register<string, string>((param) => DoString(param));
funcMapper.Register<int, int>((param) => DoInt(param));
```

Comment: this not a way to go because a func can have until 15 parameters

Comment: From the question, it seems that only one paramter is used, if not maybe the question should reflect that.

Comment: `Expression` is not covariant, so you cannot treat, for example, an `Expression<Func<string, string>>` as an `Expression<Func<object, object>>`.

Comment: @Servy `Expression<Func<TIn, Tout>>` is logically - but not technically, since only interfaces can declare variance - covariant in `TIn` and contravariant in `TOut` though. you can fairly trivially write variance converters for them - though this answer does not do that.

Comment: @Martijn But the parameters are not even logically covariant, they're contravariant, but it's used in a covariant manor, so even that wouldn't solve the problem.

Comment: Ugh, typo switching `TIn` and `TOut`. Unfortunately, C# doesn't have a bottom type to represent any `TIn`. Any variance converters need to know a specific type of the `TIn`, unfortunately.

Comment: What's your basis for asserting he can use delegates instead of expressions when he specifically said he needs to use expressions?

Comment: There's a tendency to play with Expressions when they are not really needed. My solution is for him to look at, maybe it works for him and maybe it doesn't.

Comment: Additionally, he can always get an `Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>>` in the `Register` method, compile it and then store it in the dictionary. It will make the code much more efficient if he really needs `Expression`.