# C# Generics, what does T<,> mean?

Tags: c#, generics

I have not seen this <,>-syntax before, and its impossible to google.

```
cfg.For(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>)).Add(typeof(OuterBehavior<,>));
```

.. I m guessing its some kind of wildcard, but I cant find any documentation

[Source (for example)](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Behaviors#registering-pipeline-behaviors)

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, it's an open generic type where the type has 2 parameters that are not specified. So instead of `OuterBehavior<T, U>` for example.

Comment: No, it's valid syntax. `typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>)` returns the generic type itself. If you use `typeof(IList<>)` for example, you'd get a`System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T]` Type instance

Comment: Ok, for anyone stumbling onto this SO-post, the correct answer for my question is an "unbound generic type", also see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607033/c-sharp-language-generics-open-closed-bound-unbound-constructed

Comment: Actaully the correct answer is to look it up in the language documentation.

Comment: TomTom...  my main problem was that I didnt know *what* to lookup! :) speaking of reading (the question in your case)