# How to define generic class for mapping muti-class?

Tags: c#, generics

```
public class UnityTool<IClass,cbClass>  where IClass, cbClass:class
{
    public static void UnityTest()
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IClass, cbClass>();        
    }
}
```

I'd like to create a common static method to implement the DI(Dependency Injection).
but vs2013 told me that my grammer is wrong.
how to solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic method with multiple constraints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588643/generic-method-with-multiple-constraints)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct syntax (separate the `where` restriction):

```
public class UnityTool<IClass,cbClass>
          where IClass:class
          where cbClass:class
{
    public static void UnityTest()
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IClass, cbClass>();        
    }
}
```