# How to use extends in generic for C#

Tags: java, c#

I am new to `C#`, How to use below generic for C#, i want the same as below `Java` statement in `C#`,

```
List<? extends MySuperClass> list= new ArrayList<MySubClass>();
```

`Java` allows above, can we achieve same in `C#`?

Comment: In C# is called generic constraints.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32664/1065197 http://stackoverflow.com/q/588643/1065197

Comment: And this is not a good example to use generics in Java.

Answer (score 4):

C# does not have wildcards. So the simple answer is no, there is no direct equivalent.

However, I don't think there is much point in writing that line of code in Java, because you are throwing away type information. You may as well write

```
List<MySubClass> list = new ArrayList<MySubClass>();
```

The main reason for using wildcards in Java is to allow method arguments to be as general as possible, like this:

```
static void foo(List<? extends MySuperClass> list)
```

You can do that with C# like this:

```
static void foo<T>(IList<T> list) where T : MySuperClass
```

Comment: how can i use this with variable like below
`public AbstractIBaseBo<? extends AbstractDomain> abstractIBaseBo =null;`

Comment: @AnchitPancholi I find that design really odd. You should avoid declaring fields like that.

Comment: @AnchitPancholi I don't think you can. I could be wrong as I'm not as familiar with C# as I am with Java. I think you can have an `AbstractIBaseBo<AbstractDomain>`. I also think you can have a field of type `AbstractIBaseBo<T>` in a generic class with type parameter `T` where `T : AbstractDomain`.

Comment: i will try to find out other possible solution, else i need to change my design, most possibly .