# why there two parameters in angle brackets，a class in Emgu library： Image<TColor, TDepth>

Tags: c#, emgucv

I know how to use this function according to the example，i'm just wondering is there any ways to explain this.

```
    [SerializableAttribute]
public class Image<TColor, TDepth> : CvArray<TDepth>, 
    IImage, IDisposable, ICloneable, IEquatable<Image<TColor, TDepth>>
where TColor : new(), ColorType


 Image<Bgr, Byte> img = 
           new Image<Bgr, byte>(fileNameTextBox.Text)
           .Resize(400, 400, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.Inter.Linear, true);
```

i cannot offer more information about this,Thank you!

Comment: Read about [c# generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

Comment: And then the [`Image` documentation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0-r16.12/document/html/a8929aab-99c5-79cf-385c-dcec7769fea1.htm) which describes these type parameters.

Comment: Sorry, used an outdated link, updated my comment with this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

Comment: @René Vogt  thank you ,i know the generics class<T> ,Does that mean <Bgr,byte>  is a new type .sorry to ask you again..

Comment: It means that `Bgr` and `Byte` are the generic arguments for the generic type `Image<TColor, TDepth>`. `TColor` will be `Bgr` and `TDepth` will be `Byte`. The resulting type is `Image<Bgr, Byte>`. If you know generics, I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a more basics related qustion.
You can use multiple generic types when defining a class. So `List<T>` used one, `Image<T1,T2>` uses two and `Tuple<T1,T2,...,T7,Trest>` uses up to eight in different steps (you can take a `Tuple<T1,T2,T3>` with just three generic items too). There is a lot of stuff to know about generics - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588643/generic-method-with-multiple-constraints) one for example.

But actually this question is not really EmguCV related..