# C# Multiple Generic Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, interface, repository

The code below uses a single generic parameter.

Is there a way to take multiple generic variables, where I want 2 or more classes? (eg, `T1` class, `T2` class, etc.)

**Original generic:**

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class 
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Edit(T entity);
    void Save();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic method with multiple constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588643/generic-method-with-multiple-constraints)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generics types can be anything, not just T - T just happens to be common.

Example:

```
void foo<TOne, TTwo>() 
   where TOne : BaseOne
   where TTwo : BaseTwo
```

More information can been seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters).  Check out the "Constraining Multiple Parameters" section.

Comment: Can I also just use Class, instead of Base1, Base2, like this below? void foo<TOne, TTwo>() 
   where TOne : class
   where TTwo : class

Comment: Yes, you can just use class to restrict to class types as per the table at the start of the linked article.